# PHP Error on Opencart Error Log Admin Side

Tags: php

I am seeing the following error in the Error Log in my Opencart Admin.

2021-09-16 10:59:29 - PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/site/public_html/catalog/view/theme/my-theme/template/common/header/header_12.tpl on line 95

The line with the error is as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($search_cats as $category_1) { ?>
```

What changes do I need to make and where for it to remove the error?

TIA

Full code of page below:

```html
<!-- HEADER
    ================================================== -->

<?php
$theme_options = $registry->get('theme_options');
$search_cats = $theme_options->getAllCategories();
$category_id = $theme_options->getCurrentCategory();

?>


<header class="header-type-3 header-type-12">
    <div class="background-header"></div>
    <div class="slider-header">
        <!-- Top Bar -->
        <div id="top-bar" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'top_bar_layout' ) == 2) { echo 'fixed'; } else { echo 'full-width'; } ?>">
            <div class="background-top-bar"></div>
            <div class="background">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <div class="pattern">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Top Bar Left -->
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
                                <!-- Welcome text -->
                                <div class="welcome-text">
                                    <?php if($theme_options->get( 'welcome_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') {
                                    echo html_entity_decode($theme_options->get( 'welcome_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ));
                                    } else { echo 'Welcome visitor you can <a href="' . $login . '"><b>login</b></a> or <a href="' . $register . '"><b>create an account</b></a>.'; } ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $top_block = $modules->getModules('top_block');
                                if( count($top_block) ) {
                                foreach ($top_block as $module) {
                                echo $module;
                                }
                                } ?>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Top Bar Right -->
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7" id="top-bar-right">
                                <!-- Links -->
                                <ul class="header-links">
                                    <li class="header-item language-currency">
                                        <?php echo $language; ?>
                                        <?php echo $currency; ?>

                                    </li>
                                    <!--<li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>-->
                                    <li class="account">
                                        <?php if($logged): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><i class="storm-user"></i><?php echo $text_account; ?></a>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $login; ?>"><i class="storm-user"></i><?php echo $text_login; ?>/<?php echo $text_register; ?></a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><i class="storm-shopping-bag"></i><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><i class="storm-check-square"></i><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Top of pages -->
        <div id="top" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'header_layout' ) == 1) { echo 'full-width'; } else { echo 'fixed'; } ?>">
            <div class="background-top"></div>
            <div class="background">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <div class="pattern">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Header Left -->
                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="header-left">
                                <?php if ($logo) { ?>
                                <!-- Logo -->
                                <div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Header Center -->
                            <div class="col-sm-5" id="header-center">
                                <!-- Search -->
                                <div class="search_form">
                                    <div class="button-search"></div>
                                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level search-query" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $theme_options->get( 'search_for_products_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '' ? $theme_options->get( 'search_for_products_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) : 'Search for Product...';  ?>" id="search_query" value="" />
                                    <div class="input-layer"></div>
                                    <div class="search-cat">
                                        <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0"><?php echo $theme_options->get( 'all_categories_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '' ? $theme_options->get( 'all_categories_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) : 'All categories';  ?></option>
                                            <?php foreach ($search_cats as $category_1) { ?>
                                            <?php if ($category_1['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>">- <?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>
                                            <?php if ($category_2['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($category_2['children'] as $category_3) { ?>
                                            <?php if ($category_3['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_3['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_3['category_id']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if($theme_options->get( 'quick_search_autosuggest' ) != '0') { ?>
                                    <div id="autocomplete-results" class="autocomplete-results"></div>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).ready(function() {

                                            $('#search_query').autocomplete({
                                                delay: 0,
                                                appendTo: "#autocomplete-results",
                                                source: function(request, response) {

                                                    var category_filter = $('header select[name=\'category_id\']').val();
                                                    var category_filter_url = '';
                                                    if (category_filter) {
                                                        category_filter_url = '&filter_category_id=' + encodeURIComponent(category_filter);
                                                    }
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: 'index.php?route=search/autocomplete&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term) + category_filter_url,
                                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                        success: function(json) {
                                                            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                                                                return {
                                                                    label: item.name,
                                                                    value: item.product_id,
                                                                    href: item.href,
                                                                    thumb: item.thumb,
                                                                    desc: item.desc,
                                                                    price: item.price
                                                                }
                                                            }));
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                },
                                                select: function(event, ui) {
                                                    document.location.href = ui.item.href;

                                                    return false;
                                                },
                                                focus: function(event, ui) {
                                                    return false;
                                                },
                                                minLength: 2
                                            })
                                                    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                                                return $( "<li>" )
                                                        .append( "<a><img src='" + item.thumb + "' alt=''>" + item.label + "<br><span class='description'>" + item.desc + "</span><br><span class='price'>" + item.price + "</span></a>" )
                                                        .appendTo( ul );
                                            };
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>



                            </div>

                            <!-- Header Right -->
                            <div class="col-sm-3" id="header-right">
                                <div class="header-items">

                                    <div class="header-item" id="compare-total">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $theme_options->getModel('url')->link('product/compare'); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php echo $theme_options->getTranslation( 'compare_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ), 'Compare' )   ?>">
                                            <i class="storm-balance"></i>
                                            <span class="value"><?php echo $theme_options->getCompareCount() ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="header-item" id="wishlist-total">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $wishlist ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php echo $theme_options->getTranslation( 'wishlist_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ), 'Wishlist' )   ?>">
                                            <i class="storm-heart"></i>
                                            <span class="value"><?php echo $theme_options->getWishlistCount() ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="header-item">
                                        <?php echo $cart; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $menu = $modules->getModules('menu');
                ?>
                <?php if( count($menu) ): ?>
                <div class="megamenu-background">
                    <div class="overflow-megamenu <?php echo count($menu) > 1 ? 'container' : ''; ?> modules-<?php echo count($menu); ?>">
                        <div class="relative">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($menu as $module) {
                                echo $module;
                            }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $slideshow = $modules->getModules('slideshow'); ?>
    <?php  if(count($slideshow)) { ?>
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div id="slider" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'slideshow_layout' ) == 1) { echo 'full-width'; } else { echo 'fixed'; } ?>">
        <div class="background-slider"></div>
        <div class="background">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="pattern">
                <?php foreach($slideshow as $module) { ?>
                <?php echo $module; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</header>
```

Comment: Print out $search_cats to see what it has, otherwise use the answer answered, it migh tbe null or undefined or not an array as the error message tells you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for my preference is it **foreach** values an empty array when you've got nothing, to begin with anyway.

Personally, I find this to :

```
<?php foreach ($search_cats as $category_1) { ?>
```

Replace With :

```
if (is_array($search_cats ) || is_object($search_cats ))
{
    foreach ($search_cats as $category_1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### Updated Full Code:

```
<!-- HEADER
    ================================================== -->

<?php
$theme_options = $registry->get('theme_options');
$search_cats = $theme_options->getAllCategories();
$category_id = $theme_options->getCurrentCategory();

?>


<header class="header-type-3 header-type-12">
    <div class="background-header"></div>
    <div class="slider-header">
        <!-- Top Bar -->
        <div id="top-bar" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'top_bar_layout' ) == 2) { echo 'fixed'; } else { echo 'full-width'; } ?>">
            <div class="background-top-bar"></div>
            <div class="background">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <div class="pattern">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Top Bar Left -->
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
                                <!-- Welcome text -->
                                <div class="welcome-text">
                                    <?php if($theme_options->get( 'welcome_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '') {
                                    echo html_entity_decode($theme_options->get( 'welcome_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ));
                                    } else { echo 'Welcome visitor you can <a href="' . $login . '"><b>login</b></a> or <a href="' . $register . '"><b>create an account</b></a>.'; } ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $top_block = $modules->getModules('top_block');
                                if( count($top_block) ) {
                                foreach ($top_block as $module) {
                                echo $module;
                                }
                                } ?>

                            </div>

                            <!-- Top Bar Right -->
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-7" id="top-bar-right">
                                <!-- Links -->
                                <ul class="header-links">
                                    <li class="header-item language-currency">
                                        <?php echo $language; ?>
                                        <?php echo $currency; ?>

                                    </li>
                                    <!--<li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>-->
                                    <li class="account">
                                        <?php if($logged): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><i class="storm-user"></i><?php echo $text_account; ?></a>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $login; ?>"><i class="storm-user"></i><?php echo $text_login; ?>/<?php echo $text_register; ?></a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><i class="storm-shopping-bag"></i><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><i class="storm-check-square"></i><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Top of pages -->
        <div id="top" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'header_layout' ) == 1) { echo 'full-width'; } else { echo 'fixed'; } ?>">
            <div class="background-top"></div>
            <div class="background">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <div class="pattern">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <!-- Header Left -->
                            <div class="col-sm-4" id="header-left">
                                <?php if ($logo) { ?>
                                <!-- Logo -->
                                <div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Header Center -->
                            <div class="col-sm-5" id="header-center">
                                <!-- Search -->
                                <div class="search_form">
                                    <div class="button-search"></div>
                                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level search-query" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $theme_options->get( 'search_for_products_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '' ? $theme_options->get( 'search_for_products_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) : 'Search for Product...';  ?>" id="search_query" value="" />
                                    <div class="input-layer"></div>
                                    <div class="search-cat">
                                        <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0"><?php echo $theme_options->get( 'all_categories_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) != '' ? $theme_options->get( 'all_categories_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ) ) : 'All categories';  ?></option>
                                            <?php  if (is_array($search_cats ) || is_object($search_cats )){ ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($search_cats as $category_1) { ?>
                                            <?php if ($category_1['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_1['category_id']; ?>">- <?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>
                                            <?php if ($category_2['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_2['category_id']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php foreach ($category_2['children'] as $category_3) { ?>
                                            <?php if ($category_3['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_3['category_id']; ?>" selected="selected">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } else { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $category_3['category_id']; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if($theme_options->get( 'quick_search_autosuggest' ) != '0') { ?>
                                    <div id="autocomplete-results" class="autocomplete-results"></div>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).ready(function() {

                                            $('#search_query').autocomplete({
                                                delay: 0,
                                                appendTo: "#autocomplete-results",
                                                source: function(request, response) {

                                                    var category_filter = $('header select[name=\'category_id\']').val();
                                                    var category_filter_url = '';
                                                    if (category_filter) {
                                                        category_filter_url = '&filter_category_id=' + encodeURIComponent(category_filter);
                                                    }
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: 'index.php?route=search/autocomplete&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term) + category_filter_url,
                                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                        success: function(json) {
                                                            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                                                                return {
                                                                    label: item.name,
                                                                    value: item.product_id,
                                                                    href: item.href,
                                                                    thumb: item.thumb,
                                                                    desc: item.desc,
                                                                    price: item.price
                                                                }
                                                            }));
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                },
                                                select: function(event, ui) {
                                                    document.location.href = ui.item.href;

                                                    return false;
                                                },
                                                focus: function(event, ui) {
                                                    return false;
                                                },
                                                minLength: 2
                                            })
                                                    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                                                return $( "<li>" )
                                                        .append( "<a><img src='" + item.thumb + "' alt=''>" + item.label + "<br><span class='description'>" + item.desc + "</span><br><span class='price'>" + item.price + "</span></a>" )
                                                        .appendTo( ul );
                                            };
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>



                            </div>

                            <!-- Header Right -->
                            <div class="col-sm-3" id="header-right">
                                <div class="header-items">

                                    <div class="header-item" id="compare-total">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $theme_options->getModel('url')->link('product/compare'); ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php echo $theme_options->getTranslation( 'compare_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ), 'Compare' )   ?>">
                                            <i class="storm-balance"></i>
                                            <span class="value"><?php echo $theme_options->getCompareCount() ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="header-item" id="wishlist-total">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $wishlist ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<?php echo $theme_options->getTranslation( 'wishlist_text', $config->get( 'config_language_id' ), 'Wishlist' )   ?>">
                                            <i class="storm-heart"></i>
                                            <span class="value"><?php echo $theme_options->getWishlistCount() ?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="header-item">
                                        <?php echo $cart; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                $menu = $modules->getModules('menu');
                ?>
                <?php if( count($menu) ): ?>
                <div class="megamenu-background">
                    <div class="overflow-megamenu <?php echo count($menu) > 1 ? 'container' : ''; ?> modules-<?php echo count($menu); ?>">
                        <div class="relative">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($menu as $module) {
                                echo $module;
                            }
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $slideshow = $modules->getModules('slideshow'); ?>
    <?php  if(count($slideshow)) { ?>
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div id="slider" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'slideshow_layout' ) == 1) { echo 'full-width'; } else { echo 'fixed'; } ?>">
        <div class="background-slider"></div>
        <div class="background">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="pattern">
                <?php foreach($slideshow as $module) { ?>
                <?php echo $module; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</header>
```

I hope this is very helpful

Comment: Hi Mujahid Thanks for you reply. After following your advice above. I now get the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in /home/mowersplus/public_html/catalog/view/theme/my-theme/template/common/header/header_12.tpl on line 121" Any ideas? Thank You

Comment: Please close this '}' after complete foreach loop

Comment: you have solved the issue or not?

Comment: Hi Mujahid,No not yet please can you confirm exactly what code I need to use. Thanks

Comment: I will update your code in my answer. you can check it